# Convert US Central Time to different time zones using moment JS

Tags: timezone, momentjs

I have a Date Time(**Friday, 27 October 2017 4:00:00 AM**) in US Central Time zone (CDT). I want to convert this Date Time into different time zones. These are time zones i wanted to convert.

```
Eastern Time (EDT)
Pacific Time (PDT)
New Delhi, India (IST)
Central Europian Time (CET)
Riyadh, Saudi Arabia (AST)
Pakistan Standard Time (PKT)
Lagos, Nigeria (WAT)
Australian Standard Time (AET)
Greenwich Mean Time (GMT)
Moscow, Russia (MSK)
China Standard Time (CST)
```

This is how i am doing

```
 var dateTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 4:00:00 AM", "America/Chicago");
 var IST = dateTime.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
 console.log(IST) // October 27th 2017, 9:30:00 am
```

The returned Date Time is wrong. Because **Indian Standard Time is 10 hours and 30 minutes ahead of Central Time**.

It should be **Friday, 27 October 2017 2:30 PM** (IST)

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so have you tried anything so far? It sounds like you should be parsing the value in central time, then calling the `tz` mutator as per https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/.

Comment: var dateTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 4:00:00 AM", "America/Chicago");
var IST = dateTime.tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
console.log(IST) // October 27th 2017, 9:30:00 am 
Is this code correct? Its not correct actually.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to show what you've tried - and what you expected vs what you got.

Comment: "The returned Date Time is wrong" - you *still* haven't shown what you expected to get or explained why. It also doesn't help that the value you've started with in the code example isn't the same as the one you've given at the start of the question.

Comment: Next, you should add diagnostics for `dateTime` so you can determine whether it's the *parsing* that's failing or the time zone conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't with the conversion to the Indian time zone - it's the original parsing of the Chicago time.

This:

```
var dateTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 4:00:00 AM", "America/Chicago");
```

... is treated as 4am *UTC*, and then converted to America/Chicago, so it ends up representing 11pm local time (on October 26th) in Chicago. You can see that by just logging the value of `dateTime`.

If you change the code to:

```
var dateTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 04:00:00", "America/Chicago");
```

... then it's treated as 4am local time on the 27th, which is what I believe you expected. The result of the conversion to Asia/Calcutta is then 2:30pm as you expected.

So either change the format of your input, *or* specify that format. For example, this works fine too:

```
var dateTime = moment.tz("2017-10-27 4:00:00 AM", "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a", "America/Chicago");
```

Comment: I think that format parameter in the last part of the answer should be `"YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A"` and not `"yyyy-MM-DD h:mm:ss a"`, moment has not  lowercase `yyyy` token.

Comment: @VincenzoC: Thanks, fixed.

Comment: var cst_time = moment.tz("2020-01-29 10:52:00", "America/Chicago");
 var  ist_time = cst_time .tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); 

This  worked for me. Thanks